# Is changing the margin of a rectangle a bad method for animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, margin

I am trying to create a video track bar in C# using WPF with the goal of emulating a standard track bar such as Youtube's which allows the user to drag the thumb to a new position updating the video's position in real time as it is moved.

Currently I have a dispatcher timer on the video player which detects when the video's current frame has changed at which point it calculates the thumb's (Left) margin (# of frames * pixelsPerFrame). 
When the user's mouse is pressed on the slider it then pauses the video, starts to track the mouse's X position and maps that to a frame and sets the videos current position.

It is kind of working however the motion is rather jumpy (The playback is fine, its the slider moving that is strange) and towards the end of the slider the rectangle (thumb) is kind of distorted. It gets thinner and some times actually disappears.

Is animating the slider through the margin inefficient and is there a better way to achieve this kind of (interactive?) animation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, animating the thumb via the `Margin` property is quite inefficient because it requires WPF to recalculate the layout of the control and re-render it every time there is an update.

The more efficient method of animating visuals in WPF the way you want to is to use a `TranslateTransform` attached to the item's `RenderTransform` property. Changing the `X` and `Y` properties of the `TranslateTransform` will immediately alter the item's screen location without the expensive layout recalculation. Best of all those properties are `DependencyProperty`'s so they can be data bound to properties in your view.